# Labelling a dotted arrow in tikz

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I wrote the following code, trying to get a commuting triangle with one of the arrows being dotted.

```
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.5em]
 S \ar{dr}{f} \ar{rr}{m} && Y\arrow[dl,dotted]{g} \\
&F
\end{tikzcd}
```

But the dotted arrow doesn't display the label `g` as I tried to make things.

[image: Diagram with missing g]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use almost two same options as codes:

**First 1.**

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.5em]
 S \ar{dr}{f} \ar{rr}{m} && Y\arrow[dl,dotted, "g"'] \\
&F
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

**Second 2.**

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.5em]
 S \ar{dr}{f} \ar{rr}{m} && Y\arrow[dl,dotted, swap, "g"] \\
&F
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```